# ZSH does not load my prezto profile with "sudo -s"

Tags: linux, zsh, prezto

I've install prezto as usual from my home directory and configured my favorite prompt (bigfade).

It works when I login with my current user account.

But when I make `sudo -s` to become root, my profile is not loaded as in other systems. I look everywhere and didn't see anything, my `/etc/zsh/zshrc` file is configured fine as you can see attached.

The attached picture show how my shell behaves

[image]

And the txt file is my `/etc/zsh/zshrc` file

```
# /etc/zsh/zshrc: system-wide .zshrc file for zsh(1).
#
# This file is sourced only for interactive shells. It
# should contain commands to set up aliases, functions,
# options, key bindings, etc.
#
# Global Order: zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin

READNULLCMD=${PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager}

# An array to note missing features to ease diagnosis in case of problems.
typeset -ga debian_missing_features

if [[ -z "$DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES" ]] &&
   [[ "$TERM" != 'emacs' ]]
then

    typeset -A key
    key=(
        BackSpace  "${terminfo[kbs]}"
        Home       "${terminfo[khome]}"
        End        "${terminfo[kend]}"
        Insert     "${terminfo[kich1]}"
        Delete     "${terminfo[kdch1]}"
        Up         "${terminfo[kcuu1]}"
        Down       "${terminfo[kcud1]}"
        Left       "${terminfo[kcub1]}"
        Right      "${terminfo[kcuf1]}"
        PageUp     "${terminfo[kpp]}"
        PageDown   "${terminfo[knp]}"
    )

    function bind2maps () {
        local i sequence widget
        local -a maps

        while [[ "$1" != "--" ]]; do
            maps+=( "$1" )
            shift
        done
        shift

        sequence="${key[$1]}"
        widget="$2"

        [[ -z "$sequence" ]] && return 1

        for i in "${maps[@]}"; do
            bindkey -M "$i" "$sequence" "$widget"
        done
    }

    bind2maps emacs             -- BackSpace   backward-delete-char
    bind2maps       viins       -- BackSpace   vi-backward-delete-char
    bind2maps             vicmd -- BackSpace   vi-backward-char
    bind2maps emacs             -- Home        beginning-of-line
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Home        vi-beginning-of-line
    bind2maps emacs             -- End         end-of-line
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- End         vi-end-of-line
    bind2maps emacs viins       -- Insert      overwrite-mode
    bind2maps             vicmd -- Insert      vi-insert
    bind2maps emacs             -- Delete      delete-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Delete      vi-delete-char
    bind2maps emacs viins vicmd -- Up          up-line-or-history
    bind2maps emacs viins vicmd -- Down        down-line-or-history
    bind2maps emacs             -- Left        backward-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Left        vi-backward-char
    bind2maps emacs             -- Right       forward-char
    bind2maps       viins vicmd -- Right       vi-forward-char

    # Make sure the terminal is in application mode, when zle is
    # active. Only then are the values from $terminfo valid.
    if (( ${+terminfo[smkx]} )) && (( ${+terminfo[rmkx]} )); then
        function zle-line-init () {
            emulate -L zsh
            printf '%s' ${terminfo[smkx]}
        }
        function zle-line-finish () {
            emulate -L zsh
            printf '%s' ${terminfo[rmkx]}
        }
        zle -N zle-line-init
        zle -N zle-line-finish
    else
        for i in {s,r}mkx; do
            (( ${+terminfo[$i]} )) || debian_missing_features+=($i)
        done
        unset i
    fi

    unfunction bind2maps

fi # [[ -z "$DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES" ]] && [[ "$TERM" != 'emacs' ]]

zstyle ':completion:*:sudo:*' command-path /usr/local/sbin \
                                           /usr/local/bin  \
                                           /usr/sbin       \
                                           /usr/bin        \
                                           /sbin           \
                                           /bin            \
                                           /usr/X11R6/bin

(( ${+aliases[run-help]} )) && unalias run-help
autoload -Uz run-help

if [[ -z "$skip_global_compinit" ]]; then 
  autoload -U compinit
  compinit
fi
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/terraform
```

I'm using debian jessie on this only system, the others with wheezy and Ubuntu work.

Comment: Apparently you need to install Prezto to root user's home dir if you want to use it there. A root shell won't load runcoms from `SUDO_USER`'s home.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to install Prezto to root user's home dir if you want to use it there. A root shell won't load runcoms from `SUDO_USER`'s home.
                    – 4ae1e1